# To find out whether a check box is checked from a group of check boxes that are created using a loop

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating checkboxes using a `foreach` loop. On button click the divs that are created are looped. Each checkbox is inside a div which has the same class. There are 3 divs, each containing a checkbox and I want to set the value of restricted to `true`/`false` depending on the check of check boxes

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.HealthRestrictions) {
  <div class="form-group healthRestrictions">
    <label>
      <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" class="healthresId">
      <input type="checkbox" class="healthrs" name="healthcheck"value="true"/>
      <span style="color:black" class="healthres">@item.Text</span>
    </label>
  </div>
}
```

```js
$(".healthRestrictions").each(function() {
  if ($(".healthrs:checked")) {
    IsRestricted = true;
  } else {
    IsRestricted = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: on which event you are trying to check if checkboxes are checked or not?

Comment: there i s a button  on click of that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to check if checkbox is checked or not.

Here you can iterate over checkboxes with class `healthrs` using `.each` which are under div with class `healthRestrictions`. Use `$(this)` to get the instance of checkbox which is current in the loop and use `is(':checked')` to get true for checked status and false for unchecked status of the checkbox

```js
$(function(){
  $('#result').on('click', function(){
     var IsRestricted = false;
     $(".healthRestrictions").each(function () {
     var spanText = $(this).find('span.healthres').text();
     var hiddenVal = $(this).find('input.healthresId').val();
     console.log(spanText + "  " + hiddenVal);
     if ($(this).find('.healthrs').is(":checked")) { // $(this) refers to current element 
           IsRestricted = true;
           console.log('true');
     }
     else {
          IsRestricted = false;`enter code here`
          console.log('false');
     }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group healthRestrictions">
  <label>
     <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id1" class="healthresId" value="1">
     <input type="checkbox" class="healthrs" name="healthcheck"value="true"/>
     <span style="color:black" class="healthres">@item.Text1</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group healthRestrictions">
  <label>
     <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id2" class="healthresId" value="2">
     <input type="checkbox" class="healthrs" name="healthcheck"value="true"/>
     <span style="color:black" class="healthres">@item.Text2</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group healthRestrictions">
  <label>
     <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id3" class="healthresId" value="3">
     <input type="checkbox" class="healthrs" name="healthcheck"value="true"/>
     <span style="color:black" class="healthres">@item.Text3</span>
  </label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="result" value="  Click Me  ">
```

Comment: thank you , i have one more doubt will i be able to take the value of span and hidden field which are inside that div